# Camera jerking randomly on Fallout 4

Tags: ps4, fallout-4, controllers

I just started replaying Fallout 4 again, but there's this annoying problem where every time I start to move R3, the camera jerks in the opposite direction for a split second, and it does it randomly sometimes as well. It also jerks to the left twice every time I jump. The controller I'm using has no drift and it makes aiming a problem. Plus, like I said, it's just aggravating. Anybody have a fix?
(I want to put this disclaimer here because a few people have edited my title or suggested edits saying "Whenever R3 is pressed", but that makes the reader think it's when I'm pressing it as a button or only when I'm moving. The jerking happens randomly, when I jump, or sometimes when I begin to look around. It doesn't require any input at all, just wanted to clarify that.)

Comment: Do you have a spare controller to try?

Comment: @TimmyJim I tried two different controllers and they both had the same problem.

Comment: If you have a PC plug the controller in and have a look at https://gamepad-tester.com/ to make 100% sure there's no drift etc.

Comment: are you using a DS4 controller? iirc, those have a gyroscope and maybe a subtle controller movement makes the game aim somewhere depending on the game

Comment: @AlanB I used the website and it said I was good, but just to be safe, I went to a different game and did everything that usually triggers the jerking, and nothing happened.

Comment: @prout I am, but I went into a separate game just to make sure it wasn't a controller problem and did everything that usually triggers it, and nothing happened.